# httpd.exe - Entry Point Not Found XAMPP

Tags: mongodb, xampp

I am working on some stuff for mongodb and when I try to launch Apache using XAMPP an error occurs: "The procedure entry point compiler_globals_offset could not be located in the dynamic link library D:\XAMPP\php\ext\php_mongodb.dll" I do have a comment in php.ini (D:\XAMPP\PHP) that targets it: extension=php_mongodb.dll. The launch does work if I comment the extension=php_mongodb.dll

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

I run into the same issue. But than I saw, that I had chosen the DLL for a wrong php version.
Just check for your self if you download the dll for the right php version

Comment: Please add more insights of your resolution. Best will be if you share your working code snippet here.

Comment: I can't understand your comments. First of all if you read the question you will see there is no code that could be posted here! It is about xampp setup. 2nd I gave a clear answer to the question. I run into the same error when I tried to install mongodb on my local xampp instance. Than I saw that I downloaded the mongodb dll for PHP 7.3 while my xampp runs with 7.2. After downloading the 7.2 dll, Apache started without any error message